# Where to advertise new bitcoin service?

Tags: marketing

i created new service which is using bitcoin for payment. I am bit struggling with Bitcoin community and don't know what to do next.

Recently i 
- i added service to bitcoin.it wiki
- created announcement on bitcointalk.org
- added link to reddit /r/Bitcoin

Is there any other possibilities to let the Bitcoin community know about my service?

Answer (score 1):

You've already made a post on reddit, made a thread on bitcointalk and added it to the wiki, but if you want to advertise it (as in paid advertising) then you can try the following sites:

coinurl.com - banner and text advertising, fairly cheap

bitads.net - you choose which sites you want to advertise on. can be quite cheap too

a-ads.net - no account system, just create a campaign and deposit. again, fairly cheap.

Bitcoin advertising are generally much cheaper than traditional advertising. If you accept Inputs.io, you can also get a free ad slot on Inputs' wallet page, and an instant payment button sounds perfect for selling digital files :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a service that accepts bitcoin, you should consider posting it here:

https://www.spendbitcoins.com

or specifically:

https://www.spendbitcoins.com/submit-place/